# Making a Setup.exe installation files

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012

I have created an application for one of my clients, for now I am doing instalation for that software in way I just install Sql Server 2012 (Express version), copy/paste the main .exe file (which starts the application) and also I copy all needed .dll files and one registry file.

I would like to make one Setup.exe file and when my client want to install my application he will just have to decide what will be a path where application will be installed, and all things like Sql Server 2012 Express, Registry file, .dll files etc will be installed and added into path he chosen (something like InstallSHield).

I saw that there are some alternatives for InstallShield but I'm not sure is that what I really need?

Comment: There a billion options. You could for example use [Wix](http://wixtoolset.org/).

Comment: You could have [searched](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=best+installer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WIX](http://wixtoolset.org/) is the tool of choice now that Microsoft has done away with setup projects in visual studio. I've always liked the [nullsoft installer](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/) too because of its simplicity and lightweight.

Answer (score 0):

[NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) should be fine for the things you need.

Answer (score 0):

Use [WiX](http://wix.codeplex.com/) Installer for your porposes

Comment: WiX is exactly the thing I was talking about when I mentioned some 'alternatives' but I am not sure is it possible to do everything I wrote with WiX?

Comment: I could not understand that "some alternatives" mean Wix

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anyone mentioning this so I thought that I should.

**THERE IS A SERIOUS LEARNING CURVE WITH MSI / WIX!**

- If you plan on following Windows guidelines for product installation , and have some time to learn the Wix/MSI system **then certainly use Wix** (which I recommend).
- If you are in a hurry or plan on coding around windows guidelines, **then Wix (or any MSI) will become cumbersome very quickly**.
- Installshield is NEVER the answer.  It should have died with the invention of MSI.

**Again:**

If you have NO BACKGROUND in MSI and your client needs it ASAP, I would suggest nullsoft or similar non MSI tool.

Going forward, I would learn Wix.